# Robo 3T Error : Network is unreachable

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to connect Robo 3T to my online database and it doesn't seem to be working. I am able to connect to local database with it. I tried connecting using MongoDB Compass and the Details and Auth are working fine and I am able to connect. But when I connect with the same details in Robo 3T, it doesn't seem to be working. How do I fix this?
I am using Robo 3T Version 1.1
I tried same with Robomongo 1.0, and still getting the same error

[image: Error Dialog]

Comment: Hi, have you got solution for this problem? I am facing the same error while accessing remote mongo database usint Robo 3T on my windows machine.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix that issue, I think it was the issue with that remote database alone, as I am now able to connect with other four remote database.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just change your bind_ip in /etc/mongod.conf from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 then restart the service, and it works for me~

Comment: And it is the most horrible idea to do so. Now MongoDB is exposed to each and every port of your remote machine. Let us hope you activated authentication and TLS in MongoDB and have a decent brute force blocker on the OS configured. @SaJed if it is a public server, rather use a ssh tunnel.

Comment: @silviazulinka See above

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization    Defualt ：All interface, changeed in 2.6   the default configuration file sets net.bingIp to 127.0.0.1.    When attaching mongos or mongod  to a publicly accessible interface, ensure that you have implemented proper authentication and firewall restrictions to protect the integrity of your database.

Comment: I had to do this as a quick fix; please notice that I am running MongoDB locally in docker container just as a development environment for a POC

Answer (score 11):

If you get the following error then you should also check the following:

[image: Pciture showing ROBO 3T auth options]

The atlas servers at least require this setting, if you do not choose it, then you generally get the Network is unreachable message.

Also if you are using Atlas then you should check the Authentication tab and select SCRAM-SHA-1, however this generally results in an authentication error not a network unreachable one.

Answer (score 10):

A better solution is to comment out or remove the **bindIp** setting from the config file */etc/mongod.conf*

You must restart the service for the change to take effect

Answer (score 4):

I also meet this problem when I use Robo 3T on Mac. I think there are some things you need to check to help you know what's the problem.

First try to `ping` the mongo server in your terminal to see whether you can get responses. If so, that's means you may set wrong mongo config in you Robo 3T.

If you cannot get the response, that means there is something wrong with your network. You should check your DNS and your network gateway. For example my DNS is `172.16.*` and my network gateway (execute `ifconig` and check `en0`) is `172.17.*`.  And they are not belong to the same network segment. (Actually, even if they are on the same network segment, things won't work if someone polluted your DNS server.)

**That's the problem**. The DNS that you are using cannot interpret your mongo host correctly. Someone may had polluted this DNS server.

You can have a try on `ping xxx(your mongo-server) @8.8.8.8`, which will use 8.8.8.8 as your DNS. If everything goes well, then you get the sollution.

**Sollution**: Manually set DNS for your devices. For example, Google's public DNS, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Actually, if you run `dig xxx(your mongo-server)` before and after you manually set DNS, you may find the response Ip differently.

Answer (score 2):

Go Inside bin folder of MongoDB and run `mongod` command:- `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin`
then open command prompt at this location and run `mongod` command & then try to connect with Robo 3T . It works for me.

Also create data folder inside your `C:` drive & then create a db named folder inside data folder. that's it.

Comment: This solution is working fine in my windows 7 system.

Answer (score 0):

**Start the MongoDB service from the task manager**.
Worked for me.

In my case both mongod and mongo.exe was throwing a 100 error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this symptom, and the ultimate fix is not yet captured in an answer here.

I was trying to connect to a mongo instance in the cloud using Robo 3T, and I was getting the "Network is unreachable" message.

Oddly, I could  connect from using Robo 3T inside a Parallels VM on the same machine.

This led me to try the full Studio 3T on my mac, which could also connect just fine.

Ultimately, I discovered that there was an old dotfile from an ancient version of Robomongo that was causing the problem.  `rm -rf .config/robomongo` did the trick.  Now I can connect with the ordinary, free Robo 3T.

I'm guessing that I had an expired trial of Robomongo, from back before it was free, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

sorry if i'm late to this but i was running through the same issue all morning. You have to go through a few things first so you can troubleshoot easily

1. Restart the database from the terminal, hitting the database at the correct path and let it run in the background.
2. if the database is running then go through checking the local host address, and replace it with 127.0.0.1 instead of the generic *localhost*:27017

Answer (score 0):

This might help, my robo mongo server is hosted in cloud. I have setup the mongodb but could not connect to it using Robo3T. Keeps telling network timedout (this means network problem). Been reading a lot to figure out the cause, suddenly I remembered I have also a security group in my cloud network. Just include the mongod port 27017 in the list of allowed incoming. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing the following issue when starting the Robo 3T Application:

[image: Error]

Just follow these steps, and you are good to go:

1. I'm using MacOS, so in your terminal use the following command to start your MonogDB Server:
   `/Users/vanthoff/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath=/Users/vanthoff/mongodb-data`

`mongodb-data:` Directory you must have created to store all your Data.

2. After starting the server, go to `RoboT 3T Application` and `connect to the server`. It will start working. You can also `Test` it by double clicking you MongoDB Server name. It will look something like this when it starts working:

[image]

I hope it's going to work for you too. Amigos..!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to services.msc and then search for mongodb server and then run the server in running status.
I have solved my error in this way.

Answer (score 0):

For me, reinstall mongodb and restart my computer worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As said above, this is probably due to BindIp, if you use mac and brew to install it you won't find anything in /etc/mongod.conf instead you find it in **/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf**

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Change BindIp with caution!

And same goes for running it, to start MongoDB manualy use:

`mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

or configure autostart on login with launchd by typing:

`brew services start mongodb`

I've also encountered corrupted data files on my local computer here:

```
/usr/local/var/mongodb
```

just removed them and it worked, you could see in the log that errors like:

`** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2018-08-01T00:15:50.220+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-08-01T00:15:50.220+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-08-01T00:15:50.224+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-08-01T00:15:50.303+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Downgrading WiredTiger datafiles.
2018-08-01T00:15:50.501+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1533075350:501686][3594:0x7fffb492e380], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 14/3712
2018-08-01T00:15:50.598+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1533075350:598867][3594:0x7fffb492e380], txn-recover: Recovering log 14 through 15
2018-08-01T00:15:50.664+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1533075350:663976][3594:0x7fffb492e380], txn-recover: Recovering log 15 through 15
2018-08-01T00:15:50.715+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1533075350:715398][3594:0x7fffb492e380], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2018-08-01T00:15:51.002+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-08-01T00:15:51.005+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-08-01T00:15:51.005+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62`

Answer (score -2):

This means mongo server is not started.
You need to run `mongod` command on the terminal to start the server.

if you do not have mongo db installed on your machine. Download and install from the [Link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community).

Answer (score -2):

Start your command prompt on windows.Go to the bin folder of Mongodb through command prompt and type mongod and enter.Now try to access again