# mongodb Network is unreachable on mac

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Sorry I have ask the same question again from [Robo 3T Error : Network is unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450712/robo-3t-error-network-is-unreachable)

Beacause I really can't find out the file `/etc/mongod.conf`.

My machine is `mac` and use `homebrew` install `mongodb`.

There is no `mongod.conf` in my path `/usr/local/var/mongodb`.

Any help would be appreciated.

According suggestion the path `/usr/local/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf`
[image]

My `/usr/local/opt` like this:
[image]

Try `brew uninstall mongo` and `brew install mongo`.
Connect it still get the same error.

But find the file `mongod.conf` in the path `/usr/local/etc`.

I try to remove the file and restart mongodb server then type command `mongo` get the error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-18T14:38:21.241+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

It is so strange...:(

Comment: Please check at this location: /usr/local/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf

Comment: Thanks for the help, I try the path can't find the file `mongod.conf` (update in my question). Do I miss something ?

Comment: Is this the /usr/local/opt directory?

Comment: This is my `/usr/local/opt/mongodb` if you mean `/usr/local/opt` I update it in my question too, thanks.

Comment: Please check this conversation, I hope it'll be helpful : https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/22329

Comment: Thanks, I try to uninstall mongo and install it again, it stil get the same error :( . Even I find the `mongod.conf` still can't find the solution.

Comment: @Ashish, I try to Uninstall MongoDB (MACOS) completely and type `brew install mongodb`, next type `brew services start mongodb`. My robo3T is working now, finally. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the `mongod.conf` at any folder on your Mac you like and pass the path to this file during the start of the Mongo DB server like:

```
mongod -f /path/to/mongod.conf
```

You have to create the `mongod.conf` manually e.g. on the desktop of your Mac. You can do this with the following commands.

Open a terminal

```
$ cd Desktop
$ touch mongod.conf
```

Then open the created (currently empty file) with a text editor of your choice and fill in your configurations (Here you can find a manual for the config file: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

Then start your Mongo DB server with

```
$ mongod -f /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/mongod.conf
```

Please replace YOUR_USERNAME with your MacOs username you are currently working with

Comment: Do you mean type the command on my terminal ? It will shows error `Error reading config file: No such file or directory`. Is that so ?

Comment: Thanks, I copy the code from your link's configuation and type `mongod -f /Users/MyName/Desktop/mongod.conf` get error: `Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 20315
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I Uninstall MongoDB (MACOS) completely and try again, I fix the error. Thank you.